# WKWebView navigation issue with history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView Which need to load a login page, and after successful login I need the **cookies** for further usage.

However, the login page use `history.pushState()` to redirect and refresh the page, which means `WKWebView.navigationDelegate` methods **won't trigger**, and KVO on `WKWebView.isLoading` `WKWebView.progress` also won't work.

The only property that works in this condition is `WKWebView.URL`. It will change after `history.pushState()`. However, I need the **cookies**, and WKWebView managers and synchronizes cookies to NSHTTPCookieStorage by itself. And it seems that **cookies** are not being prepared every time when the `WKWebView.URL` property got changed.

So I don't know when I can have the cookies got prepared. And because I can't modify the login page, how can I detect the navigation.